# Global Accessibility For Click Once Installation Path

Tags: vsto, clickonce, excel-addins

I have tried with google drive location as a installation path at the time of publishing VSTO application.

But at the time of installation time it throwing an exception to download manifest related stuff.

Exception is like below

```
Name: 
From: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tL4egzEy2uga0asj0bsgzQ10Y8Q-cJ3wj?usp=sharing/MyApp.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tL4egzEy2uga0asj0bsgzQ10Y8Q-cJ3wj?usp=sharing/MyApp.vsto: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: DTD is prohibited in this XML document.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Any guys having any guess regarding this exception?
Finally my intention is to be available my publish folder at global level, I will send .exe file only to user so that user can be able to install application with the combination of .exe and web location where publish stuff resides.

Comment: Like @Chris said. That won't work. Why not try pushing to Github. [Here](https://refactorsaurusrex.com/post/2015/how-to-host-a-clickonce-installer-on-github/) is an example on how to do it. It might take some time when trying the correct configuration but that might be the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: I have followed the above specified link, now I am able to do with the help of github. But finally I am getting error like '.dll.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest'

Comment: I think I solved that by recreating the whole clickonce-install and replacing all the old files (setup.exe,...). Maybe the [Project](https://github.com/lightlike/DSACharacterSheet) I am currently working on will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few questions in this same vein, and while I do not use this feature, I think I see where you're going wrong.

I believe VSTO is assuming you're deploying to your own web server, with no fancy paths. Google Drive clearly has paths that are not meant to handle appending a file or folder name. An FTP server may require login credentials or special connection settings, and is very uncommon these days.

You probably need to stand up a web server, if you don't already have one, and publish to that. Or use a network folder if that works in your situation.

Comment: I have followed the above https://refactorsaurusrex.com/post/2015/how-to-host-a-clickonce-installer-on-github/, now I am able to do with the help of github. But finally I am getting error like '.dll.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest'

Comment: Now that one I have a better answer for. You need to re-sign the deployed files any time you make changes to them. The basic pattern for doing so is 1. Remove the extra file extensions (I'm going off memory here, but I think it's .deploy) 2. Use mage or mageui to re-sign the .vsto and .manifest files, 3. Re-add the extensions.

Comment: I am new to this kind of tasks can you share a link to do that

Comment: [How to: Re-sign Application and Deployment Manifests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465299.aspx)